# How to find out which file from a theme is being used on a web page?

Tags: html, css, web, themes

I have a theme being used on a website, and I need to figure out **which html file from the theme is being used on a particular web page of the website?**

Is there a way to find that out?

Comment: Sooo... you've not really given us too much information.. I would suggest posting the code from the header section of your HTML page and we may be able to decipher from there... But in all reality we need more information from you.

Comment: If it's a static HTML page you'll see it in the URL. If it's a dynamic page then until it's shown in URL or in page code or contents there is no way to know this.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast No pointers in the header! Thank you for the response though!

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk Thank you for the to-the-point answer.

Answer (score 1):

Right click --> View Page Source.  Then there's a ton of stuff there but all the HTML code should be there, including the structure of it.

Comment: Thank you. The code can give many pointers, but I wanted to find a fool proof way just to be sure. But I learnt from Tomasz Kowalczyk's comment that there isn't any fool proof way.